# Excel 2007 VBA Syntax for Range reference that used to work, doesn't anymore

Tags: vba, excel

I hope this isn't something that has been asked before.  And I REALLY hope that there is something wrong and I'm not just missing something...

I'm making a macro in Excel 2007 to clear the input ranges in a workbook.  I'm using a CommandButton to start it and the procedure is in a module.  Using syntax like:

`Worksheets("Interview").Range("D6:D17").ClearContents`

works just fine.  However if I try to select or activate a Range on the same sheet without selecting the sheet first i get:

**Error 1004 (Select method of Range class failed)**

The following don't work to select the range

`Worksheets("Interview").Range("B17").Select`
(unless its after selecting the sheet)

or

```
    Worksheets("Interview").Select
    Range("B17").Select


    With Worksheets("Interview")
        .Range("B17").Select
    End With
```

The only way to get it to work is select the Sheet and then select the range using the full statement.  Like this:

```
    Worksheets("Interview").Select
    Worksheets("Interview").Range("B17").Select
```

I'm baffled.  I hope its not because I'm tired...

I hope I've been clear enough and used the code tags and blocks etc right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an example & hope it helps.

Consider a house which has 3 rooms (room1 , room2 & room3) in it. 
Each room has swtichboard for fan & light in it.

Now
To on/off the lights of room 1 you have press the buttons in room 1 (you have to be in room 1 for pressing the button).
To on/off the lights of room 2 you have press the buttons in room 2 (you have to be in room 2 for pressing the button).
To on/off the lights of room 3 you have press the buttons in room 3 (you have to be in room 3 for pressing the button).

If you are in room 1 you cannot on/off the lights of room2 or room3.

Same is the case here, when you are in `Worksheets("Interview")` & its active sheet then only you can select the range.

Comment: But when you're in the room you don't have to refer to the full address of the lightswitch if you only have one to choose from.

Comment: I appreciate the help Santosh.  I understand your comparison totally.  One of the problems I'm having is that even when I'm in the room with the lightswitch I have to tell it what room to turn off the lightswitch in.  Even if I've selected `Worksheets("Interview")` and made it active, I can't just use `Range("B17").Select`.  I have to use `Worksheets("Interview").Range("B17").Select`.

Comment: Then may be you in different house. Do you have multiple workbook open ? What are you trying to achieve ? Most of the time you dont need Select / Activate . Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: I don't have another workbook open, but I did add a window within excel to the same workbook.  That shouldn't make a difference should it?

Comment: @Phrayzur It should not ? `MsgBox Worksheets("Interview").Parent.Name` will show the workbook name which it refers to.

Comment: I'm actually using poor coding techniques with the select statement, but I'm past that point now.  I'm just trying to figure out why I have to use the full address within the sheet.  This is now just a learning thing. :)

Comment: @Phrayzur Do you have team viewer ? Can i see the issue ?

Comment: It's referring to the correct sheet...  Its odd.  I wonder if its because of excel crashing on this sheet the other day...

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.GoTo Sheets("Interview").Range("b17")
```

Should work

Comment: It does!  Thanks.  But why don't the others work?  They were working yesterday.  Same sheets, code and formulas.  I had the code crash the sheet but I didn't have time to test it yesterday.

Comment: Not 100% sure. I was just offering an alternative syntax

Comment: And, actually, now they are.  What am I missing?

Comment: All the examples I gave now work again.  Is this some kind of bug?  Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Are you always on the same sheet ?

Comment: It starts from the same sheet

Answer (score 0):

Ive tested it on excel 2010 and all your code is valid and works. 
You shouldn't need to select anything first no matter what version of excel you are using. 
I would suggest prefixing the worksheets("Interview") with thisworkbook eg thisworkbook.worksheets("Interview")

this way you are sure if you have multiple workbooks open that you are trying to select the correct sheet in the correct workbook.